# Zero divisors and torsion in $\mathcal{O}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: number-theory, tensor-products

Let $K$ be a (imaginary quadratic, if you wish) number field and $\mathcal{O}$ an order. I am trying to convince myself that $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}_p\subset \mathcal{O}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}_p$ contains no zero divisors, where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denotes the ring of $p$-adic integers. Thus I want to show that $1\otimes x$ is not a zero divisor. If $x$ is a unit, we are done, so in the end all that is required is to show that $1\otimes p = p(1\otimes 1)$ is not a zero divisor.

If it were, then $p(1\otimes 1)(r\otimes s) = p(r\otimes s)=0$, which implies that $\mathcal{O}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}_p$ has $p$-torsion. I do not believe that it does (all the examples of torsion in this group that I've found involve non-integers with square roots in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, such as for example $1+\sqrt{2}$ with $p=7$), but I can't see why.

Comment: $\mathcal{O}$ is free over $\mathbb{Z}$ so $\mathcal{O} \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ is free over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and in particular it has no $p$-torsion. However, it's very easy for $\mathcal{O} \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ to *not* be a domain: for instance, take $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then $\mathcal{O} \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{Z}_p[X]/(X^2+1)$. So if $-1$ is a square mod $p$, $X^2+1$ splits simply over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathcal{O} \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ can't be a domain.

Comment: Does $\Bbb{Z}_p$ denote the ring of $p$-adic integers, or the finite field $\Bbb{F}_p=\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ of $p$ elements? Either way
$$\Bbb{Z}\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}}\Bbb{Z}_p=\Bbb{Z}_p.$$